# Incorrect printing of shipping label

Tags: zebra-printer

I've just setup a Zebra GK420d on a Win 7 machine. I have a shipping label if pdf format from USPS ClicknShip. It is printing incorrectly. (see attached photo). I want to print only the left half of what you see and for it to take the entire 4x6 label. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

I've been playing with it. I have pdf now with only the shipping info but the document is still twice the size it should be. Here is a print dialog showing where I'm am now.

[image: Print Dialog]

Comment: There is no way we can tell what you are doing wrong, it depends on the printer driver what adjustments you can make to the image ups sent you..

Comment: It also depends on what you are doing, which you fail to describe.

Comment: @harrymc: I'm not sure what you mean. As I said, I am printing a pdf shipping label. What more information can I provide that would help?

Comment: Which print software? What parameters?

Comment: I've added the print dialog to the original question.

Comment: After doing some research, USPS does not provide labels that will print on 6x4 labels. "Labels will print as two (2) 4 inch by 6½ inch Click-N-Ship® Domestic labels on one piece of self-adhesive 8½ inches by 11 inches medium paper." - https://faq.usps.com/s/article/How-do-I-print-a-Click-N-Ship-label , Please also see https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/4x6-labels-on-usps-click-ship/197959.

Comment: Depending on how the PDF is made there is a small possibility that you could extract the image from the PDF. However something to consider is that if the image is distorted by any way do resizing etc the barcodes etc may not work or alternatively read incorrectly resulting in no tracking information or even the shipment being returned to shipper. If I were you I would consider looking into USPS via API (Usually you can specify label size when making shipping requests with couriers) or use an intermediary like suggested in the second link.

Comment: I had tried converting it to jpg but yeah, the resolution is not very good. And thanks for the links. Now I know why sites like stamps.com exist. You can make your comments into an answer and I will accept.